# Indentation error in def commonMenu

Tags: python-2.7, maya, indentation

I'm new to Python but known to MEL.
At the moment I try to create a menu for my specialization project (quick rigging tool).
I'm getting this error every time while I can't find a logical explanation for it.
The error is a unexpected indent, it appears in a def to create a menu.

I really try to get this thing of the ground, thanks in advance :)

The code:

```
#Python script: Autorig v0.0.1
#Interface

import maya.cmds as cmds

#Create main window
#
class AR_OptionWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = 'ar_optionsWindow'
        self.title = 'Options Window'
        self.size = (546, 350)
        self.supportsToolAction = False
    def commonMenu(self):
        self.editMenu = cmds.menu(label = 'Edit')
        self.editMenuSave = cmds.menuItem(
            label='Save Settings'
        )
        self.editMenuReset = cmds.menuItem(
            label='Reset Settings'
        )
        self.editMenuDiv = cmds.menuItem(d=True)
        self.editMenuRadio = cmds.radioMenuItemCollection()
        self.editMenuAction = cmds.menuItem(
            label='As Action',
            radioButton=True,
            enable=self.supportsToolAction
        )
        self.editMenuTool = cmds.menuItem(
            label='As Tool',
            radioButton=True,
            enable=self.supportsToolAction
        )
        self.helpMenu = cmds.menuItem(label='Help')
        self.helpMenuItem = cmds.menuItem(
            label='Help in %s'%self.title
        )
    def create(self):
        if cmds.window(self.window, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window, window=True)
        self.window = cmds.window(
            self.window,
            title=self.title,
            widthHeight=self.size
        )
        cmds.showWindow()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
# Error: unexpected indent 
# File "<maya console>", line 30 
# self.editMenuTool = cmds.menuItem( 
# ^ 
# IndentationError: unexpected indent 
#
```

Comment: Works on my machine. What's the exact error message and stack trace?

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
# Error: unexpected indent
#   File "<maya console>", line 30
#     self.editMenuTool = cmds.menuItem(
#    ^
# IndentationError: unexpected indent #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is a mix of tabs and spaces, which can lead to unexpected behavior. This is due to the [somewhat arcane rules](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) that determine how tabs are interpreted:

> First, tabs are replaced (from left to right) by one to eight spaces such that the total number of characters up to and including the replacement is a multiple of eight (this is intended to be the same rule as used by Unix). The total number of spaces preceding the first non-blank character then determines the line’s indentation. Indentation cannot be split over multiple physical lines using backslashes; the whitespace up to the first backslash determines the indentation.

[image]

In this image, tabs are arrows and spaces are dots. Your `self.editMenuAction =` line effectively has 12 spaces of indentation. Your `self.editMenuTool =` line effectively has 16.

According to [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), you should exclusively use spaces for indentation.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this makes more sense and now it works :)